# Detect local machine to void updating statistics

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, mac-address

I'm developing statistics for a website i'm developing, using PHP and MySQL.

Is there anyway to detect in PHP:

```
    //pseudo code
    If (the users machine == a certain MAC address){
       don't update the page count.
    }
```

I want to make my laptop void from updating page views on my site via MySQL.

E.g. I visit the homepage too many times. And it will make the real page visits unrealistic.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the mac address via php. PHP only can get the things what will send via the HTTP-header. Only if you are in the same network (no router between you and the webserver) it is possible.

Comment: Also, dialup users don't have a MAC address.